# Code that can be generated from 3 of 5 trusted people?

Tags: cryptography, coding-theory

Suppose a computer contains sensitive data protected by a 3-digit passcode. (I understand this does not provide much security in the real world, but for the sake of the problem, assume only 3 digits.) In order to prevent anyone from single-handedly having the ability to access the data, the passcode is divided into 5 pieces $n_{1}, n_{2}, n_{3}, n_{4}, n_{5} \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., 999\}$ and distributed among 5 trusted people.

If the majority of the trusted people agree to unlock the data, the passcode can be generated from 3 or more of the 5 parts. However, 2 or fewer of the trusted members cannot determine the passcode.

I do not understand how to formulate such an encoding scheme. I tried some approaches using polynomials and linear algebra, but I got hung up on the part about only needing any 3 of the 5 pieces.

Comment: Are we allowed any operation of the three numbers?

Comment: Yes, 3 or more of the 5 trusted members can determine the passcode by applying some operation to their "pieces."

Comment: My first thought would be that the secret is a quadratic polynomial $p(x)$, and person number $i$ is given $n_i=p(i)$. If you know any three points on the graph of a quadratic polynomial, you can recover it.

Comment: But there are some problems with the data being constrained to $0,1,2,\ldots,999$. That scheme won't work for all the possible inputs. A fix would be to pick a prime number $p$ just below $1000$ and reduce the coefficients of the polynomial as well as the pieces $n_i$ modulo $p$. Then we are working over a field, and we would be in business. The scheme does depend on person number $i$ knowing that she holds exactly the $i$th piece.

Comment: You may also be interested in [my Math.SE blog post](http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/07/24/two-points-determine-a-line-three-a-quadratic-what-has-that-got-to-do-with-cds/). You are catering for the occasion of no errors (=no malicious people among the five) and two erasures (=absentees).

Comment: I added the crypto-tag, because secret sharing schemes are IMHO more crypto than coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick two random numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ and let $P(x) = r_2x^2 + r_1 x + S$ where $S$  is the passcode.  For each person, pick a random $x_i\ne 0$ and give this person the pair $\langle x_i, P(x_i)\rangle$.

Any three people can get together and use Lagrange interpolation to find the unique $P$ that passes through all their three points.  They can then compute $P(0)$ to find the passcode.  (To do this, just solve the system of three linear equations $r_2x_i^2+r_1x_i +S = 0$ for the three unknowns $r_1, r_2, S$.)

However, with two people, there is an infinite family of 2nd-degree polynomials passing through their points  $\langle x_i, P(x_i)\rangle$ and  $\langle x_j, P(x_j)\rangle$, including one passing through $\langle 0, S'\rangle$ for every $S'$, so they learn nothing.

(Consider the analogous situation where we want *two* people instead of three to be able to get the passcode.  We pick a line $r_1x+S$ and give each person one point on the line, which by itself is useless.  But two people together have two points, which determines the line, and its $y$-intercept.)

Comment: It should be obvious, but to be rigorous, we must require that $x_i\neq x_j$ for $i\neq j$.